# Live cam voice creative

Tags: drivers

I have a live cam voice of creative, but I cannot play because I don't know how to install driver. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Have a good read through the community documentation at:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam

As it states most webcams will just 'work' on ubuntu based on a USB standard.

Most camera's USB device id's are located at http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/

I would install Cheese Webcam Booth though the software centre and see if it detects your camera when connected also